# Can you help me find out if my HP Notebook motherboard supports both M.2 SATA and M.2 PCIe SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, pci-express

I would like to purchase an SSD for my HP Notebook of the following specification [board specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGDNy.jpg)
I would like to know if the motherboard supports SSD of M.2 form factor. If it does support, I would like to know if it supports both SATA SSD and NVMe SSD. I have tried to gather specifications of the compatible SSD ([SSD SATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtT8z.png) and [SSD NVMe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Vou.png) or http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06691790.pdf and page 27) from user manual available at "support.hp.com", using my motherboard serial number, but I find the details much confusing. Based on the information I have provided, can you suggest me if I should purchase M.2 SATA SSD or M.2 PCIe SSD (Generation 3 /4).

Comment: It might be worth advising viewers that the manual for this motherboard is at http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06691790.pdf and page 27 lists approved drives including both NMVe and SATA-3 M.2 drives.  I'm no expert here, but it looks to me like it can take either.

Comment: Thank you, definitely I will add the detail you've suggested.